# Python win32com outlook keeps removing the wrong attachment

Tags: python, outlook, attachment, win32com

I have a script that is supposed to forward certain emails bases on existence of a specific type of  attachment, let's say .PDF.
I already have it sorting the emails correctly and the forwarding is perfect. The only thing is, when I try to remove the said attachment it removes a different one.
I am using the same for-loop to identify the attachments and it does recognize the one I want to remove but for some reason, the index (???) is not the same anymore and it removes a different one.
Also, I already found out that when it removes on it automatically updates the attachment indexes

```
new_mail = message.Forward()
new_mail.To = 'xxx@yyy.zzz'
attach_index=1

for attachment in attachments:        
        
        print("i can print the index correctly, and all the filename characteristic to select the one i want)

        if ***condition****:
            print('to remove...')
            new_mail.Attachments.Remove(attach_index)
        else:
            attach_index = attach_index+1

new_mail.Send()
```

in this particular case I have an email with a .pdf , a .txt and an image in the signature, that python also recognizes as an attachment. I keeps outputting "to remove...." on the correct one but removing another.
What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Your code is missing a double quote at the end of the first print.

Comment: thanks. That was not a problem. It was just to illustrate that I had the correct info at that point in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Attachment.Delete` instead of `Attachments.Remove(index)` - this way you won't have to deal with any indices.

Comment: Thank you. At first I  noticed that my Attachments was from the original message and then changed it to the new one. That helped, in part. But then I found about Delete and used that with success.